# Nidia x server settings see nothing on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia

I bought my new laptop and I decided to install ubuntu on it instead of windows, there were some problems, but I need your help with this problem. I think my drivers are not visible because I installed them and when I open the Nvidia x server setting shows nothing I will put some pictures. What can I do? Thank you anticipated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvZCb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIZsk.jpg)

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: This is usually due to a problematic installation of drivers, I suggest you downgrade your drivers to a previous version and see what happens. Personally, changing drivers fixed the issue. At times there is also a MOK management window that people miss and it results into a faulty installation.